I'm trying to use pjsip for video calling in react native. But it doesn't work
In my React native project, I want to access freeswitch data using pjsip and make video calls between two phones. Actually, one is a phone and the other is a doorbell panel with camera. Does anyone have information about this?
I'm using the note below but it doesn't help much or I don't understand it.
https://github.com/toandn96/react-native-pjsip

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hello, please what did you end up using for this project?
